# Mysqli Query Does Not Insert The First Value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I spent hours trying to figure out my problem but no luck :/ 
I am running this query:

```
if($_POST) {
    $ask_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['ask_name']);
    $ask_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['ask_email']);
    $ask_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['ask_text']);
    $ask_category = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['categ']);
    $ask_time = date("d-F-Y");

    if($ask_name = "" || $ask_email == "" || $ask_text == "" || $ask_category == "") {
        $msg = '<span class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"></span> Fill Out All Inputs Please';
    }

    else {  
        $insert_post = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO forum_posts (name, email, text, category, time) VALUES ('$ask_name', '$ask_email', '$ask_text', '$ask_category', '$ask_time')");
        header('Location: forum.php?categ=' .$ask_category);
        exit(); 
    }
}
```

This is the form in my php file

```
<!--Insert Post-->
   <form id="ask-question" method="post" name="ask_question" action="">
    <label for="ask-name">Your Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="ask_name" id="ask-name"><br>
    <label for="ask-email">Your E-Mail (Won't be displayed)</label><br>
    <input type="email" name="ask_email" id="ask-email"><br>
    <label for="ask-text">Your Question</label><br>
    <textarea name="ask_text" id="ask-text"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="post_submit" value="Ask Now" id="post-submit">
    <?php if(isset($msg)) { echo('<p>' .$msg. '</p>'); } ?>
   </form>
```

**The problem is that the query does not insert the "name" value. All other values are successfully inserted into my mysql database, but the "name" value.**

Any ideas please? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ask_name = ""` means you are assigning blank value to that variable.

Change

```
if($ask_name = "" || $ask_email == "" || $ask_text == "" || $ask_category == "")
```

to

```
if($ask_name == "" || $ask_email == "" || $ask_text == "" || $ask_category == "")
```

Comment: [Facepalm as hard as humanly possible]...Thank you very much !!!

Comment: @user3316749 :) Great it helped. Do accept answer

Answer (score 4):

You have used single `=` sign instead of double in your `if` condition.

Change

`if($ask_name = ""...`

to

```
if($ask_name == ""...
              ^
```

otherwise you are assigning empty string to that variable

Comment: Thank you too, very much !!! That was the only line I was not even bothering to check...I waas like,nah, this is too simple to be causing any problem...thanks

Comment: it is common not to see own mistakes - that's why this is good to ask...